# Storing data in a database

Tags: asp.net, database

If I have a list of movies that I am planning on storing inside of a database, and each movie has a list of strings (actors) for that movie. How do I store that?

Comment: What are you asking? How to write ASP.NET code to interact with a database? What the database design should look like? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create 3 table (for proper normalization)

1 table.> Movies (movieid,moviename)

2 table.> actors (actorid,actorname)

3 table.> movies_actor_relation (relationid, movieid,actorid)

column name ending with id are primary keys.